# Android - Detecting when user touches a drawable left

Tags: java, android, drawable, touch-event

I have a `TextView` that contains a `DrawableRight`, what I want to do is detecting when the user presses that icon in drawableRight, is that possible ? and if it is how can I do it ?

**PS:** I am working inside a fragment

**TextView XML**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:textSize="22dp"         
    android:drawableRight="@mipmap/icn" //this is the drawable
/>
```

Comment: Much better is to use an imageview and simply handle onClick

Comment: I am in a situation that forces me to use a drawable

Comment: You can have a parent Linear or RelativeLayout. put ImageView and TextView inside it like manza said. It will give same look and feel. And add touchListener to ImageView

Comment: I already have a LinearLayout parent and it prevents me from putting it side by side with the textview

Comment: What are you asking, exactly? You have a drawable on the _right_, but you want to detect a click on the _left_?

Comment: @MikeM.No, I have a drawable on the right and I want to detect when a user tap that drawable something like a `OnTouchListener()`

Comment: Then you should correct your question. You've got "right" in some places, and "left" in others. Anyhoo, the answer below is close. It should work if you change to `if (event.getX() >= mTitle.getWidth() - mTitle.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())`, and just `return true;` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
mTitle.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
   if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
   if (event.getRawX() >= (mTitle.getRight() - mTitle.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
    //drawable pressed
     return true;
        }
       }
      return false;
      }
    });
```